# Android Beginner // Why are my Variables all 0 after i should have filled them?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I just edited this post from my original one, because i could narrow the Problem down, but didn´t want to open an extra post for it.

**What i Want**
I have an Activity in which i generate Data from Houses into an Array. Then on opening another Activity the Data should be used for displaying it.

**My Problem**
The Data gets generated correctly, and I can see in my Logs that it is generated before i want to access it. At access it still doesn´t show me my Data.

**My Code**

Houses.java (Where i generate the Houses and use the Answer already given below to try to get my Data)

```
public class Houses{

int[][] NewHouseProps = new int[20][10];
int[][] HouseProps;

public Houses(){
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getClasses()
{
    ArrayList<Integer> classes = new ArrayList<>();
    Log.d("Test","ID: "+3+" CLASS: "+NewHouseProps[3][0]);
    Log.d("Test","ID: "+4+" CLASS: "+NewHouseProps[4][0]);
    for(int id=0 ; id<=8; id++) {
        classes.add(NewHouseProps[id][0]);
        Log.d("getClasses","Classes: "+NewHouseProps[id][0]);
        Log.d("getClasses!!!!!!!!!", "List: "+classes.get(id));
    }

    return classes;
}

public void GenerateHouses(){
    Log.d("Generate Houses","!!");
    for(int id=0; id<=8; id++){
            Random r = new Random();
            int h_class, garage = 0, rooms = 0, furn = 0, balkon = 0, pool = 0;
            h_class = r.nextInt(4); //Klasse
            if(h_class == 0){
                rooms = r.nextInt(4)+1;
                balkon = r.nextInt(1);
            }else if(h_class == 1){
                rooms = r.nextInt(3)+3;
                garage = r.nextInt(1)+1;
                pool = r.nextInt(1);
                balkon = r.nextInt(2);
            }else if(h_class == 2){
                rooms = r.nextInt(3)+2;
                garage = r.nextInt(2)+2;
                pool = r.nextInt(1);
            }else if(h_class == 3){
                rooms = r.nextInt(8)+6;
                garage = r.nextInt(6)+4;
                pool = r.nextInt(1);
                balkon = r.nextInt(3);
            }
            furn = r.nextInt(1);

            int price = GenerateHousePrice(id, h_class, garage, rooms, furn, balkon, pool);
            NewHouseProps[id][0] = h_class;
            NewHouseProps[id][1] = price;
            NewHouseProps[id][2] = rooms;
            NewHouseProps[id][3] = furn;
            NewHouseProps[id][4] = balkon;
            NewHouseProps[id][5] = pool;
            NewHouseProps[id][6] = garage;
            Log.d("ID: ", Integer.toString(id));
            Log.d("CLASS: ",Integer.toString(NewHouseProps[id][0]));
            Log.d("PRICE: ", Integer.toString(NewHouseProps[id][1]));
    }

}

public int GenerateHousePrice(int id, int h_class, int garage, int rooms, int furn, int balkon, int pool){

    int price = 0, pricep = 0;
    Random r = new Random();
    if(h_class == 0){
        price = r.nextInt(150000)+50000; // 50 - 200 tausend
        price += rooms * 7500;
    }
    else if(h_class == 1){
        price = r.nextInt(165000)+85000; //85 - 250 tausend
        price += rooms * 12500;
    }
    else if(h_class == 2){
        price = r.nextInt(300000)+100000; //100 - 400 tausnd
        price += rooms * 20000;
    }
    else if(h_class == 3){
        price = r.nextInt(800000)+500000; // 500 - 1.3 Mill.
        price += rooms * 15000;
    }

    if(garage > 0){
        pricep += price*0.20;
        pricep += garage * 500;
    }
    if(furn == 1){
        pricep += price*0.25;
    }
    if(balkon > 0){
        pricep += price*0.1;
        pricep += balkon*500;
    }
    if(pool == 1){
        pricep += 20000;
    }
    price += pricep;
    return price;
}
```

BuyHousesActivity.java(Here the Data should be accessed and displayed)

```
public class BuyHousesActivity extends FragmentActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buy_houses);
    Houses h = new Houses();
    ArrayList<Integer> classes = h.getClasses();
    for(int id=0;id<=8;id++){
        Log.d("OnCreate Classes: ","Classes: "+classes.get(id));
    }
    List<Integer> images = new ArrayList<>();
    images.add(R.drawable.apartment);
    images.add(R.drawable.townhouse);
    images.add(R.drawable.bungalow);
    images.add(R.drawable.villa);
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), images));

}



protected class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<Integer> imageList;

    MyViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Integer> images) {
        super(fm);

        imageList = images;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return FragmentBuyHouse.newInstance(imageList.get(position));
    }
}
```

**My Logs**
Those are the Results of my Logs, with them in place like u see above:
[Generating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p6aL.png)
[Accessing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv5sZ.png)

I hope you can help me and show me what i got wrong and/or forgot.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using a empty list. Look.

In your `FragmentBuyHouse` you call:

```
BuyHousesActivity bha = new BuyHousesActivity();
List<Integer> classes = bha.classes;
```

But when you instance `new BuyHouseActivity()`, it initialize the array, with none data.
Look your class `BuyHouseActivity`

```
List<Integer> classes = new ArrayList<>();
```

In your implemantation, you populate it array `classes` in method `onCreate()` that's not called when you instace the class. This is the reason because you have the error on line 46.

You need pass the data by parameter like you make using Bundle.

**Solution 2**

You can create a static method to return classes:

Change your `BuyHousesActivity`:

```
public class BuyHousesActivity extends FragmentActivity {

List<Integer> classes = new ArrayList<>();
private ViewPager mPager;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Houses h = new Houses(); //Activity where my Houses get generated
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buy_houses);
    Log.d("1. Step", "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
 //   for(int id=0; id<=8;id++){
 //       classes.add(h.NewHouseProps[id][0]);
 //       Log.d("Klasse: ", Integer.toString(h.NewHouseProps[id][0]));
 //   }
 //   Log.d("2. Step", "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

    /*
    classes.add(R.drawable.apartment); //Class 0
    classes.add(R.drawable.townhouse); //Class 1
    classes.add(R.drawable.bungalow); //Class 2
    classes.add(R.drawable.villa); //Class 3
    */

    mPager = findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), classes);
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);


}


public static ArrayList<Integer> getClasses()
 {
     Houses h = new Houses();
     classes = new ArrayList<>();
     for(int id=0 ; id<=8; id++) {
         classes.add(h.NewHouseProps[id][0]);
     }

     return classes;
 }


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //ViewPager Last Page or Back
    if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}
```

And you want get classes like your `FragmentBuyHouse`

```
public class FragmentBuyHouse extends Fragment {

private int[] imageResId;
private int fragnumber;
BuyHousesActivity bha = new BuyHousesActivity();
List<Integer> classes = bha.getClasses();
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i still got the same problem. I think it comes from the original variables that are somehow empty. I added my Class (Houses) in which i generate them. My Logs there show me that they get generated correctly, but when i access "NewHouseProps[id][0]" and want to set it to the class list it is always 0.